# how to set default value of a column in model using annotaion

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am trying to set default value of columns in a model in spring.
I know that i can set them as
`private boolean company=true;`

The other method of setting default value of column includes `columnDefinition` in `@Column` annotation.
I tried doing it as
`@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="boolean default true")
private boolean company;`
But in my table, value of `company` is being set to `0`whenever i run this code.I am using mysql workbench.
Am I doing it wrong? Or Are there other ways to do this?
**Edit**: I know that in my tables boolean values are not stored.Only 0 or 1 will be stored.But when i change my `columnDefinition` to `@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default '1'")` then also the value stored into tables is 0.

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` is deprecated which has the methods to enable `dynamicUpdate` and `dynamicInsert`

alternatively you can use `javax.persistence.PrePersist` annotation, its a callback executed before persist

```
private Boolean active;

@PrePersist
public void before() {
    if (active == null)
        this.active = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Database **will not** store default value as true or false for **boolean/Boolean**. It will represent the boolean or Boolean in number format (0/1) by default. If you want, you can also store it as 'Y/N' as shown below

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
public boolean getCompany();
```